# Can we pass Databricks output to function in an ADF Job?

Tags: python, json, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

Can anyone help me with Databricks and Azure function?
I'm trying to pass data bricks JSON output to azure function body in ADF job, is it possible? 
If yes, How? 
If No, what other alternatives to do the same?

Answer (score 18):

In the Notebook you can use:

`dbutils.notebook.exit(myReturnValueGoesHere)` (as already mentioned)

and then in ADF the JSON is an object that sits on output.runOutput, so `@activity('RunNotebookActivityName').output.runOutput`.

If you return:

`dbutils.notebook.exit('{"hello": {"some": {"object": "value"}}}')`

you can read in ADF using:

`@activity('RunNotebookActivityName').output.runOutput.hello.some.object`

Cool hey?

For a full list of what you can do see:

https://the.agilesql.club/2020/02/passing-status-messages-and-results-back-from-databricks-to-adf/

ed

Comment: Very nice. In addition, if you have many output values I'd highly recommend building a dictionary out of it and dumping it using `import json` and `dbutils.notebook.exit(json.dumps(ouput_dict))`

Answer (score 2):

In Azure Databricks, there is a way to return a value on exit. `dbutils.notebook.exit(myReturnValueGoesHere)`

In Azure Data Factory V2, the DatabricksNotebook activity outputs JSON with 3 fields:
"runPageUrl" , a URL to see the output of the run.
"effectiveIntegrationRuntime" , where the code is executing
"executionDuration"

If you use the above dbutils call,  a fourth field will appear in the output JSON
"runOutput" , where the "myReturnValueGoesHere" is displayed.

If you do not use the above dbutils call, you can scrape information from the runPageUrl.

Comment: Hi Martin, I tried using the same. But it doesn't work. Should i be install any libraries for it?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on which part isn't working?

Comment: Hi @MartunJaffer, I added the following line "dbutils.notebook.exit(jsonobject)" to the code, However i do not see the json being printed in the adf output activity.  
And is it possible to pass this output to function body?

Comment: Hi @Nomad18 did you manage print out the jsonobject in adf? i have similar situation here!